# Writing "Please Recycle" in Mandarin

Tags: word-choice, translation

How can one write "Please Recycle" in the context of an office paper room?
I have tried: 请回收利用 but my friend says this is only for recycling batteries.

Comment: Just for curiosity, does "Please Recycle" mean to encourage people to reuse some paper for printing?

Comment: Please Recycle is used in the United States as a message to reduce landfill waste by placing items marked as "recyclable" into specific "recycling bins" with the intent of it's resource components being reused. (Plastic, tin, metal, concrete, asphalt, paper, cooking oil, etc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think 請回收利用/请回收利用 can apply to lots of stuff as well, for example, plastic bottles, tins, cans, glass and so on.

If you really want to be specific about recycling paper, you can try

請回收廢紙/请回收废纸 = Please recycle used/unwanted paper

or

請回收紙張/请回收纸张 = Please recycle paper

Note that the above Chinese examples are written in Traditional/Simplified.

Answer (score 7):

请回收利用 is fine.  It's not limited to battery recycling.

Answer (score 5):

> 请再循环使用 Please kindly recycle and reuse

Comment: 循环使用 is reuse instead of recycle

Answer (score 2):

请回收利用 usually means waste recovery. You can try to write:

> "**回收废品**"

In the streets and lanes of China, recyclers often collect waste products, which are usually paper and some of them are electrical appliances，there are also some daily necessities.

But there（废品）is no doubt that it is absolutely useless to people.

Answer (score 1):

> - 請回收 / 請回收再造 - Please recycle
> - 請回收廢紙 / 請回收紙張 - Please recycle waste paper / Please recycle paper

*(in Traditional Chinese)*

---

### Additional information

There are Three R's.

- Reduce （減少使用）
- Reuse （廢物重用 / 重複利用）
- Recycle （循環再造）

And an additional R sometimes.

- Replace （替代使用）

Reference: [https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/環保3R](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%92%B0%E4%BF%9D3R)

Answer (score 0):

There is an elderly Chinese lady collecting bottles for years from one specific location in my yard. I have now moved the bin, I want her to know the new location, something like "Empty cans bottles HERE" and I will place a directional arrow...Thank you...

Comment: You should ask a new question instead of posting an answer here.